# Encoding a list of repeated characters in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to do the following:

```
λ> encode "aaaabccaadeeee"
[(4,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'c'),(2,'a'),(1,'d'),(4,'e')]
```

While there may be better ways to do, I'd like to know what is wrong with my code:

```
encode :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
encode [] = []
encode [x] = [x]
encode (x:xs) = (token, quantity) : encode(rest)
    where 
        let (token, after) = span (==x) xs in (token, lenght after)
```

Error:

```
/workspaces/hask_exercises/exercises/src/Lib.hs:97:1: error:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)


--  While building package exercises-0.1.0.0 (scroll up to its section to see the error) using:
      /root/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_3.2.1.0_ghc-8.10.4 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-3.2.1.0 build lib:exercises exe:exercises-exe --ghc-options " -fdiagnostics-color=always"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. What should come after `where` exactly?

**UPDATE**:

```
encode :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [(a,Int)]
encode [] = []
encode [x] = [(x, 1)]
encode (x:xs) = [(token, quantity)] : (encode after)
    where 
        (t, after) = span (==x) xs
        token = x
        quantity = length after
```

error:

```
   * Couldn't match type `(a, Int)' with `[(a, Int)]'
      Expected type: [[(a, Int)]]
        Actual type: [(a, Int)]
    * In the second argument of `(:)', namely `(encode after)'
      In the expression: [(token, quantity)] : (encode after)
      In an equation for `encode':
          encode (x : xs)
            = [(token, quantity)] : (encode after)
            where
                (t, after) = span (== x) xs
                token = x
                quantity = length after
    * Relevant bindings include
        t :: [a] (bound at src/Lib.hs:97:10)
        after :: [a] (bound at src/Lib.hs:97:13)
        token :: a (bound at src/Lib.hs:98:9)
        xs :: [a] (bound at src/Lib.hs:95:11)
        x :: a (bound at src/Lib.hs:95:9)
        encode :: [a] -> [(a, Int)] (bound at src/Lib.hs:93:1)
   |
95 | encode (x:xs) = [(token, quantity)] : (encode after)
   |                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: You want `(token, quantity):encode after`, without the `[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should come after `where` exactly?

Just the variable declarations. Not a `let` expression. I suspect you want

```
encode :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
encode [] = []
encode (x:xs) = (token, quantity) : encode rest
    where 
        (token, after) = span (==x) xs
        quantity = length after
```

But this still doesn't exactly typecheck or define the `rest` variable

Comment: `rest` should be `after` :)

Comment: could you look at my update?  `[(token, quantity)]` and `(encode after)` seems to be of the same type, I don't know why I get this error

Comment: Why did you wrap the tuple in a list? You want to prepend the tuple to the list that the recursive call returns, the line was correct in your first snippet.